# What is parent in PySide QSelectionModel.isRowSelected() function?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I need to determine which rows are selected in a [QTableView](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableView.html) associated with a [QStandardItemModel](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QStandardItemModel.html). From the view, I call the function [selectionModel()](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.selectionModel) to get the selection. This function returns a [QSelectionModel](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QItemSelectionModel.html) object. From that object, I want to call [isRowSelected()](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QItemSelectionModel.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.isRowSelected) function. This function takes two arguments: the row I want to test, and a `parent` argument, which is a [QModelIndex](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QModelIndex.html). This is where I'm lost. What is this `parent` argument for? Where does it come from? Conceptually, I don't understand why I'd need this parameter, and concretely, I don't know what value I should pass to the function to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the `parent` useful in a `QTreeView`, for example. For your use case, this are the relevant parts of the documentation:

> The index is used by item views, delegates, and selection models to
>   locate an item in the model
> **...**
>  Invalid indexes are often used as parent indexes when referring to top-level items in a model."

With `QtCore.QModelIndex()` you'll create an invalid index, that's the argument you are looking for. In this example, you can use the context menu to print the selection state of the rows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.modelSource = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        for rowNumber in range(3):
            items = []
            for columnNumber in range(3):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                item.setText("row: {0} column: {0}".format(rowNumber, columnNumber))

                items.append(item)

            self.modelSource.appendRow(items)

        self.actionSelectedRows = QtGui.QAction(self)
        self.actionSelectedRows.setText("Get Selected Rows")
        self.actionSelectedRows.triggered.connect(self.on_actionSelectedRows_triggered)

        self.contextMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.contextMenu.addAction(self.actionSelectedRows)

        self.setModel(self.modelSource)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_customContextMenuRequested)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_actionSelectedRows_triggered(self, state):
        for rowNumber in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            info = "Row {0} is ".format(rowNumber)
            if self.selectionModel().isRowSelected(rowNumber, QtCore.QModelIndex()):
                info += "selected"

            else:
                info += "not selected"

            print info

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_customContextMenuRequested(self, pos):
        self.contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.resize(333, 222)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```